# How is it possible to convert a polars dataframe to a huggingface dataset?

Tags: python, python-polars, pyarrow, huggingface-datasets

Both formats are based on arrow, but I couldn't find a way to transform one to the other.

The best I could find is:

The dataset library has a [`from_buffer`](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset.from_buffer) method that expects a `pyarrow.Buffer` object. Moreover, the polars library has a [`to_arrow`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.to_arrow.html) method that returns a `pyarrow.Table` object

Comment: Looks like `.to_pandas()` and `.from_pandas()` may be the "simplest". You can also use parquet and write to disk.

Comment: Does `Dataset(df.to_arrow())` work?

Comment: @jqurious using pandas as an "interchange" format would work, but pandas has some automatic conversions I want to avoid

Comment: @OphirYoktan can you post what error you get when trying `Dataset(df.toarrow())`

Comment: @DeanMacGregor this seems like a good direction - there are still type conversion errors

Comment: @DeanMacGregor pretty sure this is a problem with datasets in general, and unrelated to the conversion. write your comment as an answer and I'll except it

Comment: What's it say when it doesn't work? https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/blob/main/src/datasets/arrow_dataset.py. That Dataset init takes a pyarrow table. Maybe there are other Dataset classes

Comment: ValueError: Arrow type large_list<item: large_string> does not have a datasets dtype equivalent.

when providing a column which is a list of strings

Comment: I'm on mobile so I'll do it later, probably Monday, glad it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The init method of [Dataset](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset) expects a pyarrow Table so as its first parameter so it should just be a matter of

```
HG_dataset=Dataset(df.to_arrow())
```

The other methods in that class are just means to convert other structures to pyarrow. It seems as though Hugging Face datasets are more restrictive in that they don't allow nested structures so you may need to do `df.explode(List_cols).to_arrow()`